Publishing a book of poetry: Which resource to choose?
I have been writing poetry for a long time, and I had an idea of publishing my works (I did so twice in the past, but in Russian, so it was a different experience). I have a number of works on AllPoetry that I wanted to gather into a collection. I've seen that they have an option for publishing books, but I was curious whether it was a decent option to choose. I can see that they ultimately post the published books on Amazon, so they also do some kind of support.
I have been trying for years to get published in a journal, but sadly, that didn't really pan out, so I wanted to choose a platform for self-publishing, that also does some kind of promotional work. Perhaps, someone can suggest a decent platform for poetry in English? I've seen a relevant topic posted in 2019, but I was wondering whether anyone has any experience publishing in 2024.

What is your ultimate goal? Do you just want to have published a book of poetry? As an ebook or in print? Or do you want to make money selling poetry?

I am not looking to maximize income, that's for sure. The primary goal is to have the book edited, printed and promoted (on social media, or other platform(s)).

If you want a service that also promotes your book, you need to go through a traditional publisher. Unfortunately most traditional publishers won't be interested in publishing a book of poetry by an unknown poet and will reject your manuscript, because poetry doesn't sell (unless the author is already famous). No matter which channel you choose, you will have to do all your promotion yourself. Once you have a large enough following (on social media and elsewhere), every publisher will publish your poetry. So you need to build your audience first.

When I search something like how to sell poetry, I find many tutorials on how to publish and market your poems.
